# How to read an XML file using PowerShell and filter the required data

Tags: xml, powershell

How to read an XML file and extract data from that file which has large number of tags using PowerShell? I am using the below code to extract  tag, but am unable to read data from  sub tag.

```
$xmlFile= "D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac.xml"
$xmlConfig = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmlFile)
$XmlDocument.Breakfast_menu.price
```

I expect the output to read the whole xml file but unable to read whole xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <food>Belgian Waffles</food>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple 
        syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <food>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</food>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped 
        cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <food>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</food>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh 
        berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <food>French Toast</food>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough 
        bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
    <food>Homestyle Breakfast</food>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash 
        browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: I am using the below code to extract breakfast_menu tag but unable to read data from breakfast_menu sub tag.
$xmlFile= "D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac.xml"
$xmlConfig = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmlFile)
$XmlDocument.Breakfast_menu.price

Comment: Don't comment your own question, instead append these important lines to it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55992427/edit) your question and put  (the relevant part of) the xml in there. Next, ditto to what @quantummind comments

Comment: @Theo <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <food>Belgian Waffles</food>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>

Comment: @Theo Please find the relevant xml file in above comment

Comment: That's a nono I'm afraid.. As commented, click `edit` underneath your question and put the info in there in a [formatted way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189). Never paste vital information or code in a comment because that becomes unreadable very rapidly.

Comment: Simply use `$xmlconfig.breakfast_menu | Select-Object -ExpandProperty food | Out-Gridview`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading XML with PowerShell is really easy.

Suppose your xml file looks similar to this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <breakfast_menu> 
>     <food> 
>         <food>Belgian Waffles</food>
>         <price>$5.95</price>
>         <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
>         <calories>650</calories>
>     </food>
>     <food> 
>         <food>Fried Egg</food>
>         <price>$1.80</price>
>         <description>blahblah</description>
>         <calories>3500</calories>
>     </food>
> </breakfast_menu>
> ```

You simply read and have PowerShell parse the file into an object, using this

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac.xml'
```

Next, you can use the properties of this `$xml` object to get whatever it is you want to extract from it:

For instance, loop through all `<food>` items and output the information you want

```
$xml.breakfast_menu.food | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'MenuItem' = $_.food
        'Price'    = $_.price
    }
}
```

results in this output:

> ```
> MenuItem        Price
> --------        -----
> Belgian Waffles $5.95
> Fried Egg       $1.80
> ```

Or select just the one the item for 'Belgian Waffles':

```
$xml.breakfast_menu.food | Where-Object { $_.food -eq 'Belgian Waffles' } | 
                           Select-Object @{Name = 'MenuItem'; Expression = {$_.food}}, Price
```

outputs:

> ```
> MenuItem        price
> --------        -----
> Belgian Waffles $5.95
> ```

If all you are after is the price for a certain food item, you can do this:

```
$xml.breakfast_menu.food | Where-Object { $_.food -eq 'Belgian Waffles' } | 
                           Select-Object -ExpandProperty Price
```

or even shorten that code:

```
($xml.breakfast_menu.food | Where-Object { $_.food -eq 'Belgian Waffles' }).price
```

Hope that explains

---

**Edit**

If you need to do this on multiple xml files and these files are inside the **same** root path, you could loop through using `Get-ChildItem` to get the xml files and process them like in the examples I gave.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'ROOTFOLDER OF THE FOLDERS WHERE THE XML FILES ARE KEPT' -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
        # in this example simply output the menu items and their price for each xml file
        foreach ($item in $xml.breakfast_menu.food) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'File'     = $_.FullName    # added the file FullName so you know where the item came from
                'MenuItem' = $item.food
                'Price'    = $item.price
            }
        }
    }
```

Or from several locations:

```
$folders = 'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac7b5a0-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33330cbe7',
           'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\227c619a-b7d1-4da6-8fe5-f2c923ddcb7a',
           'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\d4370ae1-643f-4c44-ba41-7f640afcc276'

$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders -Filter '*.xml' -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
        # in this example simply output the menu items and their price for each xml file
        foreach ($item in $xml.breakfast_menu.food) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'File'     = $_.FullName
                'MenuItem' = $item.food
                'Price'    = $item.price
            }
        }
    }

#output to screen:
$result

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yes it helps alot but i have another xml file which has 3000 lines and by using the same method as you described i parsed the data but unable to get it. Can you please confirm is there some issue on large xml file ?

Comment: @Ali 3000 lines should not be a problem.. Study the structure carefully. Is that the same as this xml, only larger?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Can you please explain further how to parse 100xml files located at a path and grep the required data and delete the remaining data. It will be very helpful if you guide me further ??

Comment: By using the below script I am able to process a single xml file                                 [xml]$xmlDocument= Get-Content -Path "D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac\Export25.xml"
$xmlConfig = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmlFile)
$xmlDocument.Content.sessionEventTypeItem

Comment: But when I am trying to process 100 xml files it is not displaying the output. 
     [xml]$xmlDocument= Get-Content -Path 
    "D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac\Export25.xml"
    $xmlConfig = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmlFile)
    $xmlDocument.Content.sessionEventTypeItem

Comment: @Ali Where does `$xmlConfig = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmlFile)` and  `$xmlDocument.Content.sessionEventTypeItem` come in? The code is already reading the file using `[xml]$xmlDocument= Get-Content -Path "D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac\Export25.xml"`, so you proceed from there and use the `$xml` variable containing the parsed file. No need for the `$xmlConfig` line.

Comment: ok i tried and get the output just for the xml file which I have mentioned in the path in code. The problem is I have a lot of folders in which in each folder there is xml file in the subfolder . So suppose I have 100 folders in which each folder there is xml file in its subfolder . So I have 100 xmlfiles and I have to read and filter required data from that xml file using powershell code

Comment: @Ali See my edited answer to process multiple files. (this requirement wasn't in your original question though..)

Comment: By using the above code which you give I process all xml files which are stored in a single folder. I am stuck because I have xml files in different subfolders and by using the above code powershell not process xml files because the above code is for processing of xml files stored in a single folder. Sorry to bother you again can you please guide me how to process xml files which are stored in different subfolders . Forexample I have 3 xml files where file no 1 which is "Export5869712038555922725" is stored at D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac7b5a0-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33330cbe7

Comment: Continuing the above comment:: File no 1 which is "Export5869712038555922725" is stored at D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\1ac7b5a0-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33330cbe7 with other folders . File No 2 which is "Export3717960232499555274" is stored at D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\227c619a-b7d1-4da6-8fe5-f2c923ddcb7a with other folders and File No 3 which is "Export7337442610244719336" is stored at D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput\d4370ae1-643f-4c44-ba41-7f640afcc276 with other sufolders. @Theo can you please be more kind in resolving this as this will give me my desired result.

Comment: I have attached my script in the question portion @Theo . From there most probably you will get my problem and it will very helpful if you guide me where am I wrong ?

Comment: yes i checked your update answer and yes it works But I have mentioned 3 files just to explain my point . In the actual scenario I have hundred xml files at different locations which are exactly similar to the locations which I mentioned in the above comment and I want my code to  go through each subfolder of main folder and read that xml file . I don't have to initilize with 100 different paths but to autmate so that every time it picks the path of next xml file and process it ? Need your expertise here

Comment: can you please give your valuable input on above comment? @Theo need your expertise here

Comment: @Ali Ah, I misunderstood then. If the files are in the subfolerds of the three you mentioned also, just add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet and/or have the command recurse through the main root folder `'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput'`

Comment: yes by doing this I got the exact output. Moreover can you please answer on my another question which will help me in completing my project.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068708/how-to-use-if-statement-for-xml-file-in-powershell-and-how-to-remove-child-tag-a

Comment: @Ali It looks like you have edited the wrong question here and turned this one into the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068708/how-to-use-if-statement-for-xml-file-in-powershell-and-how-to-remove-child-tag-a). I have edited it back.

Comment: I click on tick here. Can you please answer my other question which is present at this link as that question is related to this topic but i thought it may be feasible for eveyone to post it as a separate question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068708/how-to-use-if-statement-for-xml-file-in-powershell-and-how-to-remove-child-tag-a