# How to use if statement for xml file in powershell and how to remove child tag and its content

Tags: powershell

How to use if statement and remove the child tag from output of that 
 if statement in xml file as from my code i parsed all xml files . 
 Now i want to check if sessionType is equal to $name which is my 
 input then remove the data between int tag.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56068708/edit) your question and show us the xml

Comment: @Theo can you please guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what the XML file looks like, judging from your code, it should look something like below:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <Con> 
>     <tar> 
>         <tri>
>             <int>
>                 <ses>Empty</ses>
>                 <description>Empty session state</description>
>                 <value>0</value>
>             </int>
>         </tri>
>     </tar>
>     <tar> 
>         <tri>
>             <int>
>                 <ses>RestrictedRemoteServer</ses>
>                 <description>Restricted remote server</description>
>                 <value>1</value>
>             </int>
>         </tri>
>     </tar>
>     <tar> 
>         <tri>
>             <int>
>                 <ses>Default</ses>
>                 <description>Default session state</description>
>                 <value>2</value>
>             </int>
>         </tri>
>     </tar>
> </Con>
> ```

In that case, this should work:

```
$name = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the sessiontype"

$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput' -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |   #'# get a collection of xml FileInfo objects
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        try {
            [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
            # get an array of child nodes where the <ses> nodes contain the wanted sessionType
            $nodes = @($xml.Con.tar.tri.int.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.'#text' -eq $name })
            if ($nodes) {
                # we have found <ses> nodes containing the wanted sessionType 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'File'        = $file.FullName  
                    'SessionType' = $nodes[0].'#text'
                }
                # loop through the $nodes array 
                $nodes | ForEach-Object {
                    ## DECIDE WHAT TO DO HERE ##

                    # remove all the subnodes of the <int> node, leaving an empty node <int></int>
                    $_.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

                    # OR: remove the <int> node completely, including all sub nodes
                    # $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

                    # OR: just remove the <ses>...</ses> subnode within the <int> node
                    # [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
                }

                # create a filename for the output by adding 'Updated' to the name
                $outputfile = Join-Path -Path $file.DirectoryName -ChildPath ('{0}_Updated{1}' -f $file.BaseName, $file.Extension)
                # save the updated XML file
                Write-Host "Saving file '$outputfile'"
                $xml.Save($outputfile)
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "File '$($file.FullName)' did not contain SessionType $name"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Bad XML file found: '$($file.FullName)'"
        }
    }

# output on screen
$result

# or save the results as CSV file somewhere
# $result | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH TO THE RESULTS CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Edit**

In case you do **NOT** want to preserve the original XML file, but overwrite it with the updated xml, use this:

```
$name = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the sessiontype"

$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Testing\TestcasesOutput' -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |   #'# get a collection of xml FileInfo objects
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_.FullName
        try {
            [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $file -ErrorAction Stop
            # get an array of child nodes where the <ses> nodes contain the wanted sessionType
            $nodes = @($xml.Con.tar.tri.int.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.'#text' -eq $name })
            if ($nodes) {
                # we have found <ses> nodes containing the wanted sessionType 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'File'        = $file  
                    'SessionType' = $nodes[0].'#text'
                }
                # loop through the $nodes array 
                $nodes | ForEach-Object {
                    ## DECIDE WHAT TO DO HERE ##

                    # remove all the subnodes of the <int> node, leaving an empty node <int></int>
                    $_.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

                    # OR: remove the <int> node completely, including all sub nodes
                    # $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll()

                    # OR: just remove the <ses>...</ses> subnode within the <int> node
                    # [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
                }

                # save the updated XML file
                Write-Host "Saving file '$file'"
                $xml.Save($file)
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "File '$file' did not contain SessionType $name"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Bad XML file found: '$file'"
        }
    }

# output on screen
$result

# or save the results as CSV file somewhere
# $result | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH TO THE RESULTS CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

When used with a user input of `Empty`, the result will be:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Con>
>   <tar>
>     <tri>
>       <int>
>       </int>
>     </tri>
>   </tar>
>   <tar>
>     <tri>
>       <int>
>         <ses>RestrictedRemoteServer</ses>
>         <description>Restricted remote server</description>
>         <value>1</value>
>       </int>
>     </tri>
>   </tar>
>   <tar>
>     <tri>
>       <int>
>         <ses>Default</ses>
>         <description>Default session state</description>
>         <value>2</value>
>       </int>
>     </tri>
>   </tar>
> </Con>
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: By running the above code I am able to remove data between int but at output directory i get 2 xml files 1st is original file and 2nd is updated file which contains the updated data that is I get the required data which removes the data which is not required but I want only 1 file at output whose name is same as original and remove the data which is not required. Sorry to bother you but can you please guide about this

Comment: @Ali Ok, changed it so it will overwrite the original xml file

Comment: The previous script which you shared was exact my requirement but i want changes in orginal file which last script was unable to do that . So after running the edited  script  no effect on tags in my orginal xml file and after running the script xml file remains as it is and there is no change . Moreover I also observe the below error on screen....

Comment: i just copied your code but it is running without any error but not deleting the tags. The error was my fault and i understand that but script don't modifying the original xml files?

Comment: kindly guide how to delete the tags in original xml file ?

Comment: I tried with every possible way but unable to change my original xml file .@Theo Code is running without a single error but don't know why i didnot get the desired output.

Comment: @Ali I can't reproduce that. All my test xml files with the EXACT same structure as in the example get updated fine. Because of the error you mentioned, I have added a `try{..}catch{..}` block, so it does not break on badly formed XML files. Having said that, XML is **structured** data, meaning that in this case, we follow the nesting of tags in this order: `<Con><tar><tri><int><ses>`. If your xml files have different structure, you should have posted an example to show that. Check if the files to be updated are not opened by some other application, perhaps preventing them to be overwritten.

Comment: ok i am checking the issue. Meanwhile can you please share the code which creates a new modified updated file as you share before . It helps me in troubleshooting .

Comment: @Ali I have now posted both versions, but really.. you should have kept the script I posted before..

Comment: can you please elaborate as from the above code all the tags between int tag has been removed and at the output xml i get the tag <int> <int>. @Theo I also want to remove <init> <int> these 2 lines also such that there will be no int tags when condition satisfied. Moreover as from the updated file code I get the output xml as Export586_Updated and I want the name of new xml as Updated_Export586

Comment: I have shared my required output xml file in question. @Theo By looking at this you will be clear about it .

Comment: @Ali Have you even tried to **READ** the code? What you now seem to want, contradictory to what you say in the question is ALREADY THERE. I'm signing out here now because honestly.. With SO it is **expected/mandatory** you make some effort yourself. The very least you can do is read carefully and try to learn from the code given.