# Deleting a specific tag in xml file

Tags: powershell

I am stuck in the code as I want to delete a specific tag from xml file. Actually my code finds the seType tag in xml file and delete data between in node which is working as per my expecations but I also want to delete that specific in tag also but unable to find solution for this. For example, when I give seType 921 then it will delete all the tags between  tags but it will not delete  tag

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56068708/9898643)

Answer (score 2):

I would select the `in` node using XPath with `Select-Xml` instead, and then call `RemoveChild` to specifically remove that node:

```
$array = @($xml |Select-Xml -XPath "//in[se/seType[. = $name]]" |Select-Object -Expand Node)

$array | ForEach-Object {
  $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
} |Out-Null
```